Populating recursive element from distinct child node XSLT
Im trying to look down a level in an XML document, select distinct values and the populate new elements for each distinct value.  for example.  take the input xml of
    <Invoice>
      <InvoiceNumber>99-99</InvoiceNumber>
      <Customer>ACME</Customer>
      <Lines>
          <Line>
            <LineNumber> 1 </LineNumber>
            <Color> Blue </Color>        
          </Line>
          <Line>
            <LineNumber> 1 </LineNumber>
            <Color> Blue </Color>        
          </Line>
          <Line>
            <LineNumber> 1 </LineNumber>
            <Color> Red </Color>        
          </Line>
          <Line>
            <LineNumber> 1 </LineNumber>
            <Color> Yellow</Color>        
          </Line> 
       </Lines>
   </Invoice>

Sample XSLT
<xsl:for-each select="/Invoice/Lines/Line/Color[not(.=preceding-sibling::Line/Color)]">
            <Colors >
                <ID><xsl:value-of select="/Color"/></ID>
            </Colors>     
            </xsl:for-each>

Desired output
<Colors>
  <ID>Blue</ID>
</Colors>
<Colors>
  <ID>Red</ID>
</Colors>
<Colors>
  <ID>Yellow</ID>
</Colors>

However, I can only seem to get this to output
<Colors>
  <ID>Blue Red Yellow</ID>
</Colors>

What am i doing wrong?

You tag your question as XSLT 2 and ask for distinct values but don't use distinct-values(//Color)? That seems the main issue, there is a function to return the distinct values from a sequence of values, so use that.

Indeed, the method you are attempting to use (incorrectly) is the worst possible method  for this. Even in XSLT 1.0.

Correct, Im not leveraging the distinct-values function.  I was trying to do a for-each element with the not(.=preceding-sibling) functionality.  either way, I can loop but I cant seem to output the value per iteration

Any suggestions on how to do accomplish this?

Well, if you use <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(//Color)">, then inside you output the current context item with e.g. <xsl:value-of select="."/>.

I tired something similar to what you have, but because of my location in the document, it output "." incorrectly.  I did just achieve the desired result using combination of for-each-group group-by="Color" and value-of select="current-grouping-key()"....thoughts??

This stylesheet:
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/Invoice">
    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(Lines/Line/Color)">
        <Colors>
            <ID>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </ID>
        </Colors>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

when applied to your example input, will return:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Colors>
   <ID> Blue </ID>
</Colors>
<Colors>
   <ID> Red </ID>
</Colors>
<Colors>
   <ID> Yellow</ID>
</Colors>

It would probably be better to do something like:
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/Invoice">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(Lines/Line/Color)">
            <Colors>
                <ID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                </ID>
            </Colors>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

to get a well-formed XML document and to remove the redundant spaces:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Colors>
      <ID>Blue</ID>
   </Colors>
   <Colors>
      <ID>Red</ID>
   </Colors>
   <Colors>
      <ID>Yellow</ID>
   </Colors>
</root>

